# getting jscrollpane to work on a div containing a datatables table

Tags: datatables, jquery-jscrollpane

the logic and setup:

'wrapper' div is a set height and width.

[jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) is set to be applied to 'wrapper' div.

'wrapper' div contains text above an instance of a [datatables](http://datatables.net/) table (which is itself in another div).

desired outcome:  jscrollpane is applied to 'wrapper' div.

current outcome:  jscrollpane is not appearing and 'wrapper' div is not a scrollable area.

i don't have a link to a test site and setting this up in jsfiddle is going to be a doozy (but i'll start on it now and post link asap).

**update:** hmm, i seem to have it working on a jsfiddle [(http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/AGf9M/)](http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/AGf9M/) but not test site :(

perhaps it is because on the test site i am using data from a database and the height of the datatables table is not there until after the data has loaded?  therefore the scrollpane is not triggered?  i don't know :(

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable();
$('#wrapper').jScrollPane();
} );
```

can jscrollpane work on a div that contains a nested div and table?  or is it possibly just a conflict between jscrollpane and datatables scripts (firebug shows no errors)?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution seemed to be setting the height of the table with:

```
"sScrollY": "300",
"bScrollCollapse": false
```

this somehow gave jscrollpane enough information to be triggered to create a scrolling area to accommodate the height.